# Checking if words from a text file have been inputted, not working

Tags: python, text-files

I have written a program that gets a random word from a text file, scrambles it, and asks the user to unscramble it. It checks if the user is right by comparing the answer with words in the text file, but it doesn't work. Any ideas why?

```
lines = fo.readlines()

while playing:

        word = random.choice(lines) # picks a random word from the dictionary

        convertWord = list(word) # Converts it to a list

        random.shuffle(convertWord) # Shuffles the list

        print("Your word is: ",''.join(convertWord)) # joins the list into a string
        ans = str(input("Unscramble! "))


        for line in lines:
            if ans in lines: # checks if answer is in dictionary
                print("correct")
            else:
                print("incorrect")
```

I expect it to say correct or incorrect and loop back to the top, but the output is always incorrect.

Comment: Could you add the input txt file and the input user provided? making it a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Each of your `lines` ends with a newline `\n`, `strip` it before comparing. Also, there is no need to loop on the lines to check if your word is one of the lines. Furthermore, you still have the orginal `word`, so there's no need to look for it in the lines.

Answer (score 0):

This is because readlines returns a list of lines where each element on the list ends with newline character `\n` but when the user inputs the word, it does not include a newline character. You can use `rstrip()` to remove newline character from each line of your dictionary.

```
import random

dictionary = ["umbrella\n", "shelter\n", "hostile\n", "exchange\n", "maverick\n"]

lines = [line.rstrip() for line in dictionary]

word = random.choice(lines) # picks a random word from the dictionary

convertWord = list(word) # Converts it to a list

random.shuffle(convertWord) # Shuffles the list

print("Your word is: ",''.join(convertWord)) # joins the list into a string
ans = str(input("Unscramble! "))

for line in lines:
    if ans in lines: # checks if answer is in dictionary
        print("correct")
    else:
        print("incorrect")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the new line character at the end of every word, since you're reading them from a file. And at the end, you still have the original word, so there's no need to parse the lines for it again.

You can make these changes:

```
word = random.choice(lines).strip()

...

if ans == word:
    print("correct")
else:
    print("incorrect")
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue is with the lop at the end.
You may be searching with the entire line as a word. May be you can share a hard coded example of your input? (lines)

Any way, i have modified it a bit and it works

```
import random
words = ["cat","dog","bird"]
word = random.choice(words) # picks a random word 

convertWord = list(word) # Converts it to a list

random.shuffle(convertWord) # Shuffles the list

print("Your word is: ",''.join(convertWord)) # joins the list into a string
ans = str(input("Unscramble! "))

if ans == word: # checks if answer is correct
  print("correct")
else:
  print("incorrect")
```

Now you need to figure out how you want to fill "words" :)

Comment: The main problem comes from the newlines included at the end of the lines when reading from a file. As your code doesn't read from a file, it isn't relevant to this question.